# jQuery Nested ul with li's parent child, show hide

Tags: jquery, menu, accordion, html-lists

I'm trying to create a simple accordion menu where ul's nested in an li are hidden until the parent li is clicked which will first hide all other nested ul's if exposed and then expose the nested ul of that li.

The only other catch is that I want to remove the href for the parent li.

I've achieved most of this except my nested ul li's are inheriting the aforementioned actions even though I'm targeting the li's parent class. I know I'm missing something fundamental. Thanks in advance

HTML

```
<ul>
  <li.expanded><a href="foo">Lorum</a>
    <ul>
      <li.leaf><a href="foo">Lorum</a></li>
      <li.leaf><a href="foo">Lorum</a></li>
      <li.leaf><a href="foo">Lorum</a></li>
      <li.leaf><a href="foo">Lorum</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li.expanded><a href="foo">Lorum</a>
    <ul>
      <li.leaf><a href="foo">Lorum</a></li>
      <li.leaf><a href="foo">Lorum</a></li>
      <li.leaf><a href="foo">Lorum</a></li>
      <li.leaf><a href="foo">Lorum</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li.expanded><a href="foo">Lorum</a>
    <ul>
      <li.leaf><a href="foo">Lorum</a></li>
      <li.leaf><a href="foo">Lorum</a></li>
      <li.leaf><a href="foo">Lorum</a></li>
      <li.leaf><a href="foo">Lorum</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li.expanded><a href="foo">Lorum</a>
    <ul>
      <li.leaf><a href="foo">Lorum</a></li>
      <li.leaf><a href="foo">Lorum</a></li>
      <li.leaf><a href="foo">Lorum</a></li>
      <li.leaf><a href="foo">Lorum</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('ul ul').hide();
    $('ul li.expanded a').removeAttr("href");
    $('ul li').click(function(){
      $('ul ul').hide('slow');
      $(this).find('ul').toggle('slow');



    });
 });
;
```

Answer (score 4):

There were some typos in the html, I have the changed li.leaf to class='leaf'. I have changes in the script too. To hide all the sub ul's css is used.
See it in action : http://jsfiddle.net/theuideveloper/DFHWd/4/
Hope this helps you.
Happy coding!
-theUiDeveloper

**HTML**

```
<ul id="master">
  <li class="expanded"><a href="foo">Lorum1</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="leaf"><a href="foo">Lorum</a></li>
      <li class="leaf"><a href="foo">Lorum</a></li>
      <li class="leaf"><a href="foo">Lorum</a></li>
      <li class="leaf"><a href="foo">Lorum</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="expanded"><a href="foo">Lorum2</a>
    <ul>
      <li.leaf><a href="foo">Lorum</a></li>
      <li.leaf><a href="foo">Lorum</a></li>
      <li.leaf><a href="foo">Lorum</a></li>
      <li.leaf><a href="foo">Lorum</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="expanded"><a href="foo">Lorum3</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="leaf"><a href="foo">Lorum</a></li>
      <li class="leaf"><a href="foo">Lorum</a></li>
      <li class="leaf"><a href="foo">Lorum</a></li>
      <li class="leaf"><a href="foo">Lorum</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="expanded"><a href="foo">Lorum4</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="leaf"><a href="foo">Lorum</a></li>
      <li class="leaf"><a href="foo">Lorum</a></li>
      <li class="leaf"><a href="foo">Lorum</a></li>
      <li class="leaf"><a href="foo">Lorum</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**css**

```
ul#master ul{
display:none;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
            $('ul li.expanded a').each(function(i){
            var subUl = $(this).parent().find('ul'); //Get the sub ul.
            $(this).bind('click',function(e){
                    e.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default action of the link
                    $('.expanded ul').hide(); // hide all the other ULs
                    subUl.toggle();
                }) ;   
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

You could change your jQuery as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('ul ul').hide();
    $('ul li.expanded a').removeAttr("href");
    $('ul li.expanded > a').click(function(event) {
        $('ul ul').hide('slow');
        $(this).parent().find('ul').toggle('slow');
    });
});
```

The problem was that child elements of the targeted `li` were [bubbling](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html) their `click` event up, triggering `li.expanded`'s click event handler.  I've changed the selector to target the `a` directly under an `li` with class `expanded`.

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/ybVFj/

Also, your HTML should look something like this:

```
<ul>
    <li class="expanded"><a href="foo">Lorum</a>
        <ul>
            <li class="leaf"><a href="foo">Lorum</a></li>
            <li class="leaf"><a href="foo">Lorum</a></li>
            <li class="leaf"><a href="foo">Lorum</a></li>
            <li class="leaf"><a href="foo">Lorum</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="expanded"><a href="foo">Lorum</a>
        <ul>
            <li class="leaf"><a href="foo">Lorum</a></li>
            <li class="leaf"><a href="foo">Lorum</a></li>
            <li class="leaf"><a href="foo">Lorum</a></li>
            <li class="leaf"><a href="foo">Lorum</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="expanded"><a href="foo">Lorum</a>
        <ul>
            <li class="leaf"><a href="foo">Lorum</a></li>
            <li class="leaf"><a href="foo">Lorum</a></li>
            <li class="leaf"><a href="foo">Lorum</a></li>
            <li class="leaf"><a href="foo">Lorum</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="expanded"><a href="foo">Lorum</a>
        <ul>
            <li class="leaf"><a href="foo">Lorum</a></li>
            <li class="leaf"><a href="foo">Lorum</a></li>
            <li class="leaf"><a href="foo">Lorum</a></li>
            <li class="leaf"><a href="foo">Lorum</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```